# Xamarin forms development on LinuxMint

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, android-emulator, linux-mint, mobile-emulator

Is there any way that we can build/debug and run xamarin forms app on linuxMint?

Alternatively is there any way that we can run visual studio 2019 on Linux apart from using vine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way that we can build/debug and run xamarin forms app on linuxMint?

Sorry , there is no way to build /debug a xamarin froms app on Linux OS from officail supports.

However , about **[Xamarin.Android on Linux](https://github.com/0xFireball/xamarin-android-linux)** , you can have a look at that .Although that not tested on **linuxMint** , also can have a try whther it also works on **linuxMint** .

> Alternatively is there any way that we can run visual studio 2019 on Linux apart from using vine?

(Hoping that Microsoft will release Visual Studio for Linux soon)

But Microsoft hasn’t made it’s Visual Studio Open Source. So it isn’t Available for Linux Systems.

You can only Install **Visual Studio Code** for Linux Systems , which is an amazing Code editor for Programmers.

[image]

More reference: **[Visual Studio Code on Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux)**